# Connecting to Postgres from R causes authentication failure

Tags: r, postgresql, docker

I'm trying to connect to a postgres db running in docker from R. I'm getting password authentication failed from R but not from the command line.

Start container:

```
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 --name my-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword postgres
```

Access from within the container works:

```
docker exec -it my-postgres bash
psql -U postgres
```

Access from the host works from cl:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -W
```

But for some reason connecting from R gives me an authentication fail:

```
library(DBI)
db <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres(),
                dbname = 'postgres',
                host = 'localhost',
                port = 5432,
                user = 'postgres',
                password = 'mysecretpassword')
```

Error message:

```
Error: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Versions:

- RPostgres 1.4.3
- DBI 1.1.2
- R 4.1.1
- postgres:latest - 14.1

Comment: Postgres version and RPostgres versions needed? Add as update to question.  Also add the exact error message. A guess is that you are using Postgres 14 and `R` database driver that does not understand new `SCRAM` authentication.

Comment: RPostgres 1.4.3, DBI 1.1.2, R 4.1.1, postgres:latest so 14.1

Comment: I also tried it with RPostgres 1.4.3.9000 which is the github development version and had the same result

Comment: Hmm, that error looks like a problem with the actual password. Two possible causes 1) If the password is being passed in as variable it is not an exact match to what is needed. 2) You are not connecting to the Postgres instance you think you are and it is the wrong password for that instance. Look at the Postgres log for the server you are trying to connect to and see if the connection is actually reaching it.

Comment: Okay this is interesting, typing a bad password from the command line gives me a log in strout but attempting from R does not. I have no idea what else it could be trying to connect to, its my only running container and I dont have postgres on my host machine.

Comment: Look at the Postgres log for the Postgres instance you think you are connecting to. If that is the correct instance it will show the failed attempt and give more information about why it failed. If you don't see the failure then you know you are trying to connect to another instance.

Comment: Yes, glance at the logs. That was my beef minutes ago on my box when `dpkg` / `apt` had removed the `identd` daemon I needed in the local setup (one main user, some DBs without password, all long runnig but a little ... artisinal.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver That was it, I have no idea how that was happening but R was trying to connect to a different postgres instance I guess. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R was trying to connect to the wrong instance of postgres, after changing the port binding to something else (5432:5432 -> 8543:5432) I got connected to R.

How this happened I have no idea. It is my only running docker container, I dont have postgres on my host machine and connecting through the CL when bound to the standard port got me into the correct instance. Also I thought I would have gotten a port conflict from Docker if trying to use an in use port but that didn't happen either.

Comment: So now if you do `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres` from host command line what happens?

Comment: `psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?` So thats weird

Comment: No that is correct,  the port being exposed on the host should be `8543` now not `5432`. So, `psql -h localhost -p 8543 -U postgres` should work?

Comment: Exactly, so what was I successfully connecting to before with psql? Why do R and psql connect on when it is running on port 8543 but only psql connects when it is running on 5432 (and R seems to be authenticating off something but clearly not what psql was hitting)? _Its not super important because this seems to solve the issue it just seems weird_

Comment: I don't know. I have seen weird behavior when `/etc/hosts` has been fooled around with, so it might not hurt to look there. If it happens again a `ps ax | grep post` would be a good idea to see what is active.

Comment: Maybe glance at the config files such as `pg_hba.conf` . `localhost` via 127.0.0.1 or socket may have different access requirements than coming via the host, a different IP address, and a different set of rules.